# how to show markers only in gmscircle region otherwise hide in ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, gmsmapview

how to show markers only in `GMSCirle` region otherwise hide in iOS , I have created `GMSCirle` using google maps, now I wanna display markers only on the region of `GMSCirle` otherwise hide markers.

here is my code :

```
GMSMarker *centerPoint=[GMSMarker markerWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(16.301687, 80.419235)];
    centerPoint.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"PinImage.png"];

    circ.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05];
    circ.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    circ.strokeWidth = 5;
    circ.tappable=true;
    circ.map = mapView_;
    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton=YES;
    mapView_.settings.zoomGestures=YES;
    mapView_.settings.zoomGestures=YES;
    mapView_.settings.compassButton=YES;
    mapView_.settings.rotateGestures=YES;
    mapView_.settings.scrollGestures=YES;
    mapView_.settings.tiltGestures=YES;
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled=YES;
```

I struggled a lot if any idea would be appreciable , Thanks in advance.

Simply i just wanna know how to display markers only on particular region in iOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following simple idea for it.

```
-(BOOL) checkMarker:(CLLocation*)locB

{
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc]
                    initWithLatitude:24.590095
                    longitude:73.698256];

CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
NSLog(@"%f",distance);

if(distance <= RADIUS)
{
    NSLog(@"You are in Circle ");
    return true;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"You are not in circle");
    return false;
    }
}
```